# Strange error in apt-get download (bug)

Tags: debian

Running here Debian 9.5/Antix 17 in amd64, in a Lenovo ThinkPad E560.

I am having a strange error in `apt / apt-get` when doing `apt-get download sudo`.

Interesting enough, it only happens *when running the command as root*.

```
# apt-get download sudo
Get:1 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 sudo amd64 1.8.19p1-2.1 [1,055 kB]
Fetched 1,055 kB in 2s (352 kB/s) 
W: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/home/xdlta55/sudo_1.8.19p1-2.1_amd64.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
```

The error also won't appear if the deb file is already there.

I thought a `apt download` should have it's bussiness finished as soon at it downloaded the deb file, What is happenning here?

PS. I know this command can and should not be run as root.
PPS. `strace` did not show anything meaningful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems this situation has a bug open *and accepted*, already filled as related bug #885928 in the Debian bug report tracker

[apt: warning installing local files: N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root ...](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=885928)

> I just installed some debs from a local directory using apt. After the
>   install completed I got a warning about how the download was done
>   unsandboxed because _apt got permission denied reading the files. This
>   is because my home directory is 0700. I'm not sure that the sandboxing
>   for reading files off the local disk is a useful thing to do but the
>   warning definitely isn't a useful thing to print.

It is also filled as bug #866329, that is exactly my case

> The sandbox warning is unnecessary when apt is installing a local file
>   that shouldn't really be downloaded. Please don't show this warning in
>   that case.

More interestingly enough, #903552, also an accepted bug [apt: complains about "unsandboxed download" and undocumented config parameter "pkgAcquire::Run"](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=903552)

> Note that the supposed config parameter "pkgAcquire::Run" is unknown
>   to the apt(8), apt-get(8), and apt.conf(5) manual pages, as well as
>   the file "/usr/share/doc/apt/examples/configure-index.gz", which is
>   supposed to be "an index of all APT configuration directives".

So aparently, we are dealing with a bug in software, and a 2nd bug in the documentation, and both are already filled in the Debian bug tracking system.