# Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file 'ffmpeg_4.2.2-1.dsc' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)

Tags: kali-linux, nvidia, ffmpeg, graphic-card

I ran the following commands to get the ffmpeg in Kali Linux as root. I got the tutorial link from [This Link](https://www.maketecheasier.com/nvidias-gpu-assisted-video-encoding-nvenc-work-ubuntu/)

`sudo apt-get build-dep ffmpeg
 sudo apt-get install libfdk-aac-dev
 sudo apt-get source ffmpeg`

The error comes after the last command (`sudo apt-get source ffmpeg`)

Below is the full output

`dpkg-source: info: extracting ffmpeg in ffmpeg-4.2.2
dpkg-source: info: unpacking ffmpeg_4.2.2.orig.tar.xz
dpkg-source: info: unpacking ffmpeg_4.2.2-1.debian.tar.xz
dpkg-source: info: using patch list from debian/patches/series
dpkg-source: info: applying 0001-avcodec-arm-sbcenc-avoid-callee-preserved-vfp-regist.patch
dpkg-source: info: applying 0002-avcodec-libtwolame-fix-mono-default-bitrate.patch
W: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file 'ffmpeg_4.2.2-1.dsc' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)`

Comment: `W:` means it's a warning, not an error. Anyway the last command shouldn't have to be run as root

Comment: See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908800/what-does-this-synaptic-error-message-mean) or [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/468807/strange-error-in-apt-get-download-bug) or these bug reports: [#866329](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=866329), [#885928](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=885928), [#930667](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=930667) or [this for Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/synaptic/+bug/1522675)